# Windows 8 not booting any more

Tags: 12.10, grub2, dual-boot, windows-8

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 alongside Windows 8 after [this guide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HANcetKsqc). Now I can't boot Windows 8 any more. When I choose it in the GRUB screen, it shows me some kind of error, and after pressing enter it says: "A disk reading error ocurred, press ctrl+alt+del to reboot". When I reboot, it's just the same again. Ubuntu is booting normally...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah that link was for win7 and Ubuntu 12.04. There is a problem with win8.  Microsoft Windows 8 really created a mess for all Linux distributions.Your system has UEFI activated.which has to be deactivated. Follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-system) to install Ubuntu on a system which has win8 preinstalled. 
You will have to follow the steps as mentioned.You will also have to re-install Ubuntu.

Comment: but windows 8 was not pre-installed on my computer, i installed it over windows 7... does that make a difference?

Comment: no it doesn’t make a difference. Just follow the link. :)

Comment: oh great now i tried installing windows 8 from dvd but it doesn't recognize any partitions -.-

Comment: why do you want to reinstall win8? you will have to only re-install Ubuntu.